# How to override the needle API when creating a blueprint?

Tags: jhipster

I'm actually working on a .Net Core blueprint for JHipster. The file tree is not the same as for the Java version and the needles don't work anymore. I need to override the needles in order to modify the paths in it.
How to make the generator using the blueprint's needles and not the original ones ?

I tried to extends the needles and to modify the paths in it but they are not taken into consideration. The JHipster's needles are always used. I also tried to see how the others blueprints as ViewJS and Kotlin manage the problem but no one override the needles. I also tried to find a documentation on the needle API but there is none.

For example, the client's entities are no longer generated at the same path. So I tried to override the needle-client-angular.js.

```
const chalk = require('chalk');
const _ = require('lodash');
const needleClientAngular = require('generator-jhipster/generators/client/needle-api/needle-client-angular');
const constants = require('generator-jhipster/generators/generator-constants');
const dotnetConstants = require('../../generator-dotnetcore-constants');
const jhipsterUtils = require('generator-jhipster/generators/utils');
const toPascalCase = require('to-pascal-case');

const CLIENT_MAIN_SRC_DIR = `${dotnetConstants.SERVER_SRC_DIR}${toPascalCase(this.baseName)}/ClientApp`;

module.exports = class extends needleClientAngular {
    ...

    addEntityToMenu(routerName, enableTranslation, entityTranslationKeyMenu) {
        const errorMessage = `${chalk.yellow('Reference to ') + routerName} ${chalk.yellow('not added to menu.\n')}`;
        const entityMenuPath = `${CLIENT_MAIN_SRC_DIR}app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.html`;
        const entityEntry =
            // prettier-ignore
            this.generator.stripMargin(`|<li>
                             |                        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="${routerName}" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" (click)="collapseNavbar()">
                             |                            <fa-icon icon="asterisk" fixedWidth="true"></fa-icon>
                             |                            <span${enableTranslation ? ` jhiTranslate="global.menu.entities.${entityTranslationKeyMenu}"` : ''}>${_.startCase(routerName)}</span>
                             |                        </a>
                             |                    </li>`);
        const rewriteFileModel = this.generateFileModel(entityMenuPath, 'jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-menu', entityEntry);

        this.addBlockContentToFile(rewriteFileModel, errorMessage);
    }

    ...
}
```

Currently, I get this error, proof that the needle override is not used :

> Unable to find
>   src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.html or missing
>   required jhipster-needle. Reference to bank-account not added to the
>   menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the only way I found to do it is to replace needles paths from the blueprint client subgenerator directly into the generator-jhipster node module. I know it's not clean but it's not a priority and we will certainly make something better in the future.

The related issue :
https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-dotnetcore/issues/11